# how to delete blob element from a table in sqlite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am sending bytearray to insert an blob element it is inserting as png image it is working.But i want to delete blob element for these i am sending bytearray to column but it not deleting.

```
public void deleteImage(Byte[] bytearray)
 {
  try{
   database.execSQL("DELETE FROM deleteImage "+" where image='"+bytearray+"';");
  }
  catch(Exception e){
   e.toString();
  }
  }
```

Comment: try Triming the column value & your argument value.

Comment: sai is ketan answer working ???

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
  database.execSQL("DELETE FROM deleteImage WHERE image=\""+bytearray+"\" ;")

or 

mDb.delete(deleteImage,"image=\""+bytearray+"\"", null);

mDb.delete(deleteImage,"image = '"+bytearray+"'", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I managed to find solution for querying with blob in the where clause, but not for delete. So at the end my solution was first to query the row(s) that I want to delete and than use the row ID to delete it. Here is the code sample. I assume that you have column named ImageId as primary key of type int.

```
    public Cursor queryImage(final byte[] data, String[] columns) {
    return getReadableDatabase().queryWithFactory(
            new CursorFactory() {

                @Override
                public Cursor newCursor(SQLiteDatabase db, SQLiteCursorDriver masterQuery, String editTable, SQLiteQuery query) {
                    query.bindBlob(1, data);
                    return new SQLiteCursor(db, masterQuery, editTable, query);
                }
            },
            false,
            "FavoriteData",
            columns,
            "Image = ?", null, null, null, null, null);
}

public void favoriteDelete(byte[] byteArray){
    Cursor cursor = queryImage(byteArray, new String[]{"ImageId"});
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        getReadableDatabase().delete("FavoriteData",
                "ImageId" + "= ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0))});
    }
}
```

If somebody has better solution, I will be interested too. Anyway if you have any way to avoid using Blob to query it will be better, cause it is not so efficient. You can try with identifying the images somehow, for example using the image data hash for searching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (It works for me):

UUID is stored as BLOB

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+DBHelper.USER_TABLE+" WHERE "+DBHelper.USER_UUID+"=?",
            new Object [] { uuidToByteArray(user.getUuid()) }
```

Documentation: [SQLiteDatabase execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]%29).

According to documentation, **byte[]**, String, Long and Double are supported in bindArgs. However, it is **not** recommended to use this method for executing SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements. I don't know why.

```
public void execSQL (String sql, Object[] bindArgs)
```