# Why do some SQLite methods expect arguments as an Object[] while others need a String[]?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm curious about the design of the [Android SQLite API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). For example, we have

```
public void execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)
```

for SQLs that don't return data, and we also have

```
public Cursor rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)
```

for SQLs that do return data.

Why are the arguments expected as an Object array in the former and as a String array in the latter case? I understand that accepting only Strings might make sense due to SQLite's [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity). However, if that is the case, why not consistently use String arrays for arguments? Is there some non-String argument that makes sense for `execSQL` but not for `rawQuery`?

Comment: As far as I can see it's just a side-effect of the `SQLiteCursorDriver` interface which is used by `#rawQuery(..)`. The actual implementation uses a `SQLiteQuery` (a subclass of `SQLiteProgram` - which is also the base of the `SQLiteStatement` class used by `#execSQL(..)`).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, accepting only strings does *not* make sense because strings never compare equal with numbers, i.e., queries like

```
c.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE some_number_column = ?", args);
```

will never return any records with numbers. (You would have to declare all columns as `TEXT`, and never use expressions or convert them with something like `CAST(... AS TEXT)`.)

Jens mentioned a possible explanation, but that is no excuse for inconsistent and plain bad design.

Comment: Actually, `c.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE _id = ?", String.valueOf(myId))` *does* work, even if _id and myId are declared as integers. Apparently, SQLite does some conversion magic here (in the "right" direction). Comparisons (greater than, smaller than) work as well.

Comment: The conversion magic is [explained here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#expraff). In a nutshell, if `some_number_column` has affinity `INTEGER` and `?` is passed as a `TEXT`, `?` is treated as `NUMERIC` instead. Thus, numeric comparisons work *as long as the parameter is compared directly to a numeric database field*.

Answer (score 0):

There is one. For example if you want to compare BLOB values. Have a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543595/how-to-delete-blob-element-from-a-table-in-sqlite-android/27465556#27465556).

UUID stored as BLOB

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+USER_TABLE+" WHERE "+USER_UUID+"=?",
        new Object [] { uuid.toByteArray }
```

According to documentation, **byte[]**, String, Long and Double are supported in bindArgs. However, it is **not** recommended to use this method for executing SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements.

I just don't know why.