# How to search a database with integer types in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

That question bothers me since the begining of SQLite in Android. Selection arguments are `Strings`. What? Why?

Let's have a look at my issue. I've got a database properly filled:

```
sqlite> select count (*) from issues where project_id = 1;
3819
```

Great. Let's have a look at the code:

```
public Cursor selectAllCursor(final long projectId) {
    final String selection = projectId > 0 ? KEY_PROJECT + " = ?" : null;
    final String[] selArgs = projectId > 0 ? new String[] {
        Long.toString(projectId)
    } : null;

    final Cursor c = mDb.query(TABLE_ISSUES, null, selection, selArgs, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

Well, that returned `Cursor` is empty. Why?

```
sqlite> select count (*) from issues where project_id = '1';
0
```

Well, that's why.

The only fix I found is:

```
public Cursor selectAllCursor(final long projectId) {
    final String selection = projectId > 0 ? KEY_PROJECT + " = " + projectId : null;
    final String[] selArgs = null;

    final Cursor c = mDb.query(TABLE_ISSUES, null, selection, selArgs, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

It works, but I find this ugly.
Why aren't the selection args an array of `Object` instead of `String`? The Android framework would test the object type, and if it's an integer (`int`/`long`), it'd tell SQLite to treat this as an integer.

Comment: According to a comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13255659/752320), you can use `String.valueOf(int)` and it will behave properly. Still ugly, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are useful to avoid string formatting problems (including SQL injection attacks).
With other types, you do not have such problems.

But this still means that you have to use completely different code depending on the type of the value.
Additionally, if you are using [compileStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29), you *can* use other types as parameters, but [SQLiteStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) works only for a single value (1 x 1) result set.

This is just plain bad API design.

If you declare your table column as `INTEGER`, SQLite's [type affinity rules](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) will automatically convert the value back into a number.
However, this works only for direct comparisons like `Column = ?`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#query%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is pretty clear that the parameters will always be bound as strings. Not sure **why** that is (as that's your actual question :-) ), but can't find any way around it.

> selectionArgs You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in order that they appear in the selection. **The values will be bound as Strings.**

A "nicer" way of doing what you have up there is perhaps using [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)? 
e.g.

```
String selection = String.format("%s = %d", KEY_PROJECT, projectId )
```